# how to print the column of a file in unix recursively?

Tags: bash, unix

I want to print the columns of a file in unix to a temp file.Below is the code that i have wrote but its not giving proper output.

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_DATE=`date +'%d%m%Y'`
Temp_Path=/appinfprd/bi/Scripts/IRP/New_Vendors/
IRP_PROJECT/SXM_SFTP/*/INBOUND -type f head -1|xargs -0 ls -al  > "$Temp_Path/Column_$CURRENT_DATE.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with find command only

```
find \
IRP_PROJECT/SXM_SFTP/*/INBOUND \
-type f \
-exec head -1 {} \; \
 > "$Temp_Path/Column_$CURRENT_DATE.txt"
```

Comment: @igrI am getting an error "paths must precede expression Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]"

Comment: i have tried  sed -n 1p /trmoutcv/CVCIMOUTPUT/*.* >>/appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/New_Vendors/Column.txt , now i am getting the columns how do i get filename as well? i want to differenciate the columns by file names.